# Is there a tool like 'watch' that can view cyclical output given a repeat marker

Tags: text-processing, logs, text-formatting

This seems to come up a few times. I'll be trying to spot differences in logs with repeating cycles. For example:

```
start
1
2
3
end
start
1
2
4
3
end
```

Rather than scrolling through pages of terminal output it would be nice to have some structure to the log. The tool `watch` can run a command at some interval, and even highlight changes with `-d`. Is there an easy way to split up the output from a program that prudces the above into blocks between start/end?

Just viewing changes in real-time from a fixed line within the cycle would be nice so I could spot changes. Being able to scroll through cycles would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote something small in the meantime. It's not great but gets the job done.

https://github.com/pknowles/watch_cycles

```
cat log.txt | ./watch_cycles "start"
```

Shows, for example:

```
page 2/2
start
1
2
4
3
end
```

Arrow keys scroll to previous pages.

Answer (score 0):

A new utility [`pw` (PipeWatch)](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/) has a feature for exactly this.

```
tail -f log.txt | pw
```

`pw` pumps data through an internal FIFO buffer, from which snapshots are taken, displayed, and pushed into a 20-screen-deep snapshot history, which can easily be visited using the up/down arrow keys or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

By default, snapshots are taken every 10 seconds, or whenever there is a 1 second read timeout, and of course these timeouts can be adjusted.

The **trigger** feature causes the unchanging parts of repeating patterns to freeze on the screen. You can see this in the demo video.

However, you can easily put `pw` into trigger mode, using commands similar to Vi searching: `/pattern` and `?pattern`. In trigger mode, the display updates whenever a match occurs against one or more lines in the FIFO. There is a lot more to it.

You can specify triggers before you start the program like this.

```
# trigger: match foo on line 1, bar on line 3
pw -e /foo -e 3/bar
```

If you have your triggers and other settings set up the way you like them, you can save the session with `:s filename`, and recall with `pw -f filename`; the session has your filters and triggers, plus display settings like the configuration of vertical splits. The file just contains `/`, `?` and `:` (colon) commands, which you can easily edit to adjust.